# adding a custom JS button into a preexisting div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i need to make a custom JS button into a preexisting div. I can make a button appear on the body, but i can't seem to make it inside any div.

my code structure would be along these lines

```
<html>
<body> 
<div id="placeButtonHere"> </div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function myFunction()
    {
        var btn=document.createElement("BUTTON");
        document.body.appendChild(btn);
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

this works to create a button on the body, however it doesn't work when i try to make it into the div. 
I have tried

```
$('#placeButtonHere').append(btn).html();
```

as well as a few different iteratinos of that code. and it just can't seem to work.

NOTE: At my school where i am writing this now JSfiddle is a blocked site so i wont be able to use them.
thanks

Comment: In your 'working example' you use native JS, in your non-working it's jQuery. And the jQuery formula is wrong, it should be `$('divToAppendTo').append(btn);` (no .html())

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
<html>
<body> 
<div id="placeButtonHere"> </div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function myFunction()
    {
        var btn=document.createElement("BUTTON");
        document.getElementById("placeButtonHere").appendChild(btn);
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```